# Camel Split aggregator to merge exchanges as List

Tags: split, apache-camel, aggregate

I am simply trying to split a list of Map instances , process them in a bean and merge them in a list object. So I have made this:

```
<camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="ref:contactHistoryDbRead"/>
            <camel:split parallelProcessing="true" streaming="true" strategyRef="groupedExchangeAggregationStrategy">
                <camel:simple>${in.body}</camel:simple>
                <camel:bean ref="contactHistoryRequestTransformer" method="transform"/>
            </camel:split>
            <camel:bean ref="contactHistoryService" method="createContactHistory"/>
            <camel:to uri="ref:contactHistoryDbUpdate"/>
        </camel:route>
```

In the end, it splits the `List<Map>` object, process them but just after the end of split, when I want to get the whole items as a List, it gives me only one of them.

Is it because of the `org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy`? how can I make this?

My camel version is: 2.11.2

Thx

Comment: Which version of Camel are you using?

Comment: Edited. Pleaase have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delay in answering. According to the [Apache Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html):

**Camel 2.2 or older:**

The Splitter will by default return the last splitted message.

**Camel 2.3 and newer**

The Splitter will by default return the original input message.

This is the default behaviors for a splitter *without an aggregation strategy*. So in your case after the split is completed you will receive the original message which in your case is the Map which you sent originally. However you are providing an aggregation strategy which is overriding the default strategy.

If you were running 2.2 and older you would need to implement the aggregation strategy. So just try this route:

```
<camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="ref:contactHistoryDbRead"/>
        <camel:split parallelProcessing="true" streaming="true">
            <camel:simple>${in.body}</camel:simple>
            <camel:bean ref="doSomeprocessingOnTheMapBean" method="transform"/>
        </camel:split>
        <camel:bean ref="convertMapToListBean" method="TransformMapToList"/>
        <camel:to uri="ref:aBeanThatConsumesTheList"/>
</camel:route>
```

Shout if you need more information.

Comment: My camel version is: 2.11.2 , it is not older but newer. So is there a default aggregation strategy in Camel to do this?

Comment: Yes this means version 2.3 and newer.

Comment: So is there a default aggregation strategy in Camel to do this?

Comment: Yes as stipulated in documentation. If you send list,map or collection to splitter from 2.3 and up your recieve the original message. Then you can process this message further.

Comment: As you have said, it gives me the original List. But I want to have the list item whose items are processed in split. Not original one